# React-select select menu list support html tag

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm wondering if it's possible to enable html-tag support in [**react-select**.](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

I'm using promise callback function to inject list of suggestion, and have added `<em>`tag into the results..

But there's no way to tell react-select consider it as html tag.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the optionRenderer property for this, and define a custom method that returns your element. This can contain html.

See example of this in [react-select documentation](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/CustomRender.js).

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this as a string, and use [Dangerously Set innerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to display it in your component.

Comment: Thanks Pcriulan
I'm aware of Dangerously Set innerHTML, but my case is something else... i'm using third-party library namely react-select which get you in trouble to use Dangerously Set innerHTML as a common way.